# Exporting imports using module.exports and ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to import a function into a file and then export it from that file. This should be straightforward but for some reason I cannot get it to work.

search_action.js

```
function search_actions() {

    this.receive_results = function() {
        return {
            type: 'RECEIVE_RESULTS',
            results: results
            }
        }
}

module.exports = search_actions
```

index.js

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var SearchActions = require('./search_actions.js') 
var search_actions = new SearchActions()
//console.log(search_actions.receive_results)
export search_actions.receive_results
```

The export at the bottom of index.js fails with unexpected token despite the fact that console.log(search_actions.receive_results) prints the function. So what is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: *"unexpected token"* Means that you have a *syntax error*. It has nothing to do whether or not `search_actions.receive_results` has the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your re-export is not valid:

```
export search_actions.receive_results
```

You can't use a `foo.bar` reference on the right, as the export needs an unqualified name. You can reference the field within an object declaration and export that:

```
export default {
  search_actions: search_actions.receive_results
}
```

See [section 15.2.3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports) of the spec for the export syntax. The problem you're running into is the `x.y` part of the export, which an object or local variable will resolve.

If you were using the ES6 `import` as well, you could also do:

```
import {receive_results} from 'search_actions';
export default receive_results;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either. This works: export function receive_results(results) {
 return {
  type: 'RECEIVE_RESULTS',
  results: results
 }
}

Comment: But I'm trying to avoid having to write that in index.js (would rather import from search_actions.js and then export the returned function)

Comment: If you use `import` or assign the function to a variable, you can do that. You really just need an un-dotted reference.

Comment: as you say,                                                                                                    var receive_results = search_actions.receive_results
export { receive_results }